# How can I segment a colored line?

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv3.0, cg

I'm trying to segment the blue and black line of this image.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZR9F.jpg)

but I was unable to segment them separately (using the OpenCV library in Java) and it resulted in this:

[binarized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWZ1J.jpg)

I tried this function:
`mgproc.threshold(imgGray, imgThreshold, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);`

> How can I segment the blue and black lines separately using the OpenCV library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the colors of the lines are a given, you can define a color range and filter the image.

Here is a sample code (not mine; taken from this website: https://pythonprogramming.net/color-filter-python-opencv-tutorial/)

```
lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
```

Comment: I used the "inrange" method and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try using `adaptiveThreshold`, and tune to your needs.

```
 // Adaptive Threshold
 Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(test_image, test_image, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15,2);
```

See more Java [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc&method=adaptiveThreshold)